# how to allow user re subscribe Sendgrid nodejs?

Tags: node.js, sendgrid, subscribe

I am sending emails to users using [@sendgrid/mail](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs/tree/main/packages/mail) in nodejs. Users are able to unsubscribe to mails.

Once the user is unsubscribed, I want to provide a link to user to subscribe again.

For example,

[image: unsubscribe to subscribe]

As per the screenshot attached, on click of "**this link**" I want to subscribe the users again.

Please let me know how can I get the re-subscribe link to users.

Comment: I don't **think** you can do this, I think the user will have to click the `unsubscribe` on older messages and will have to re-enable from there (at least when using suppression groups on sendgrid)